# Cyclic fragment backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have 5 fragments in my app. I use backstack. When I open fragment, he added to backstack.

> [Fragment1]->[Fragment2]->[Fragment3]->[Fragment4]->[Fragment5]

And when I click back-button I need to open 2 latest fragmets cyclically.

> [Fragment4]->[Fragment5]->[Fragment4]->[Fragment5]->[Fragment4]->[Fragment5]

Is it possible?

Comment: I am not sure of what you are asking here. But it looks like you just need a custom implementation of onBackPressed method of your root activity. Just check, what fragment is on the top of stack, and implement to load the fragment off the stack logically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved. I use backstack without repeating fragment. It's better!